# How do I schedule an app to launch on Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, scheduled-tasks, at

How would I launch a graphical application, like firefox or gnome-calculator, at a certain time. `at` does not work for this; i.e. `echo "firefox" | at now` does not launch firefox. Cron might work but that would set up a repeating task. Is there a way to set such an app to launch with the same functionality as at, being at a specified time or a set amount of time from now?

Comment: Using `at` or `crontab` implies that it is a background task. As such, they generally have no notion whether you are running a gui or even logged in. They are therefore the wrong tools to use. If you are running `KDE`, this has the `kalarm` facility which should work for your purpose. I have no idea what is available in `Gnome`.

Comment: `kalarm` looks like a good suggestion. It would be appreciated if anyone can suggest a desktop-agnostic (or even gnome-specific) analogue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kubuntu 22.04 LTS, X11, KDE. All I need is to "manually" retain `DISPLAY`.

In general `at` retains the environment from the time of invocation, except few variables. `DISPLAY` is one of the exceptions. See `man 1 at` for details. The lack of the variable is why `echo "firefox" | at now` doesn't work.

This is how you can retain `DISPLAY`:

```
echo "DISPLAY='$DISPLAY' firefox" | at now
```

The command will break if `$DISPLAY` expands to something that includes `'`; but it shouldn't in practice. Usually the expanded string is just `:0` or so.

You can schedule for later, just don't log out of your desktop. I *suppose* you can specify a not-yet-existent display for `firefox`, create the display before the time comes, and it will work; I haven't tested this scenario though.